# How to access and filter array of data within if statement in Tyoescript

Tags: arrays, typescript, if-statement, filter

I need to filter an array of objects base on some conditions but I cannot access the array data within the if condition therefore I cannot filter the data, how do I approach this issue please?

```
data =[
    {
        color: "red",
        value: "#f00"
    },
    {
        color: "green",
        value: "#0f0"
    },
    {
        color: "blue",
        value: "#00f"
    },
    {
        color: "cyan",
        value: "#0ff"
    },
    {
        color: "magenta",
        value: "#f0f"
    },
    {
        color: "black",
        value: "#000"
    }
]


selection: string = "";

onClick($event: any) {
      this.selection = $event.value
    }


filterArray(): void {
    let myData = this.data
    if (this.selection != null) {
      let filteredData = myData.filter(x => x.color == "black" && x.value == "#000");
      console.log(filteredData) // this is not logging
    }
    else {
      console.log(myData) this also is not logging
    }
  }
```

Comment: What is value of the `condition` variable?

Comment: the condition is,  if (myData != null)

Comment: If neither branch of the if is executed, that can only mean that your `filterArray` function is not called.

Comment: @ghybs answer seems to work for me. Can you please share what your expected results are and what you are receiving instead?

Comment: @W-B Could you please check now, I have updated the code above

Comment: What is your expected result? What errors are you getting?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure to quote string values.

In your filter callback:

```
x.value == #000

// Should have been:
x.value == "#000"
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-odTpdlDU6CT6FM8D6cEQSDuTMOLPOlxut3QQA)

Comment: That was a typo, fixed but it does not resolve the issue

Comment: The playground linked in above answer shows that the code works, once the typo is fixed. Either one or the other of your `console.log()` is correctly executed.

Comment: This answer seems to work for me. Can you please share what your expected results are and what you are receiving instead?